# Inno Setup desktop shortcut (link) which has "Run as administrator" advanced property set

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut-file, windows-shortcut

I am struggling to get Inno setup (5.5.9u) to created a desktop shortcut that has an icon and has the advanced property of *"Run as administrator"* set.

**Issue**

This question, is a little different than: [How to set 'Run as administrator' on a file using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978917/how-to-set-run-as-administrator-on-a-file-using-inno-setup)

Since what I am trying to do is not run a program at setup time with admin rights, (setup is already running at Admin), but rather leave a link on the desktop that has has the *advanced* property of *"Run as Administrator"*.

**Code Sample**

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\EGPL Watson Uninstall"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\DashBoard"; \
    Filename: "{app}\dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\electron.exe main.js"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}\dashboard"; \
    IconFilename: "{src}\dashboard\build\configure.ico"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*First, make sure you have a very good reason to run your application with Administrator privileges. User applications should not need Administrator privileges. If they need it, it's usually a sign of a bad design. One common (bad) reason to want an application to run with Administrator privileges, is that the application needs to write to its installation folder.*

See [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848)

---

Inno Setup does not natively support creating a shortcut with *"Run as Administrator"* flag set.

The *"Run as Administrator"* flag is a bit in the .lnk file. See:

- [LinkFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/ae350202-3ba9-4790-9e9e-98935f4ee5af) in [MS-SHLLINK]: Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format
- [How to create a Run As Administrator shortcut using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28997799/850848)
- [How can I use JScript to create a shortcut that uses "Run as Administrator"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11162802/850848)

You can set the bit using the following code:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
  AfterInstall: SetElevationBit('{userdesktop}\My Program.lnk')
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure SetElevationBit(Filename: string);
var
  Buffer: string;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Filename := ExpandConstant(Filename);
  Log('Setting elevation bit for ' + Filename);

  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
  try
    Stream.Seek(21, soFromBeginning);
    SetLength(Buffer, 1);
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, 1);
    Buffer[1] := Chr(Ord(Buffer[1]) or $20);
    Stream.Seek(-1, soFromCurrent);
    Stream.WriteBuffer(Buffer, 1);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

*Tested on Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6). But it should, even more naturally, work on Ansi version too.*